# How to exclude dynamic URL in ngx-ui-loader?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-fullstack, ngx-ui-loader

I am using ngx-ui-loader in my angular app to show the loading spinner. I want to exclude some of the URL but I am setting the base url of the API dynamically (http://localhost:8080) through services. Below is my code:

1. **Service for defining the base URL**

routing-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { API_URL } from '../app.constants';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingService {

  BaseUrl : string;

  constructor() { }


  getBaseUrl():string {
    if(location.origin==="http://localhost:4200") {
      this.BaseUrl = API_URL;
    } else {
      this.BaseUrl = location.origin;
    }
    return this.BaseUrl;
  }

}
```

2. **app.module.ts** code

```
NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({
  exclude: ["https://localhost:8080/api/auth"],
});
```

In my case, I want to set the given BASE URL (https://localhost:8080) through my service and add it to exclude array that is defined in **app.module.ts**. Any suggestion regarding same will be helpful.

I had also tried the given below code as mentioned in documentation but that doesn't work for me
https://tdev.app/ngx-ui-loader

```
NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({ exclude: ["/api/auth"] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You  mention non secure http at the start of the question... maybe that's the problem? Try removing the `s` in `https`... would be nice if that's all it was

```
NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({
  exclude: ["http://localhost:8080/api/auth"],
});
```